# Using browsersync with XAMPP

Tags: gulp, xampp, browser-sync

I use XAMPP as an Apache Server and as described here https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-proxy
i do the following in gulp:

```
 browserSync.init({
    proxy: "localhost/mysite.de/DEV_F3/public_html",  
 });
```

But BS opens my browser at "localhost:3000/mysite.de/DEV_F3/public_html" which gives me a 404.
Why does it add that port 3000 and how do I get this to simply work?

Answer (score 3):

For your gulpfile.js you may change the following line to include your XAMPP port:

```
 browserSync.init({
    proxy: "localhost/mysite.de/DEV_F3/public_html",
    port: 8000  
 });
```

so that when gulp initiates, it will run

`localhost:8000/mysite.de/DEV_F3/public_html` in the browser **instead of**

`localhost:3000/mysite.de/DEV_F3/public_html`

*Note: The port is either 8000 or 8080, depending on your config.*

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Check your Xampp port, because if for some reason you have changed the default Xampp port, you need to put the new port of your Xampp. Another part that you can check is also your Virtual Hosts and Hosts this if you are using Windows OS.

**Directories:**

```html
C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra -> httpd-vhosts.conf
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc -> hots
```

After checking these settings you can use [browsersync](https://browsersync.io/docs/options#option-port) following the official documentation.

Come on, go to your **gulpfile.js**

```html
browserSync.init({
    proxy: "localhost:8080/mysite.de/DEV_F3/public_html",  
 });
```

When running your on your terminal you will have this return on your browser

```html
gulp watch
```

Location:

```html
Local:http://localhost:3000/mysite.de/DEV_F3/public_html
```

I hope it has helped or directed you to a greater understanding.

Comment: This has helped me, thank you.
One small typo in "Directories":
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc -> hosts

Comment: it's may be almost to close the solution, but i have a porblem. It just loading all time never execute any thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
browserSync.init({
    proxy: "localhost/mysite.de"
    online: true  
 });
```

This is assuming that 'mysite.de' is the root directory of your site. 
The 'online' part supposedly helps with performance.